# SQL: count days from table based on month

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone,

I have this query on a mysql database:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 1 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mongen,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 2 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monfeb,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 3 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monmar,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 4 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monapr,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 5 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monmag,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 6 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mongiu,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 7 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monlug,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 8 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monago,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 9 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monset,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 10 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monott,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 11 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) monnov,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 12 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mondic
    FROM shipping_details
    WHERE DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday'
    UNION
    SELECT DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 1 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuegen,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 2 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuefeb,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 3 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuemar,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 4 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tueapr,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 5 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuemag,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 6 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuegiu,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 7 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuelug,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 8 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tueago,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 9 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tueset,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 10 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tueott,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 11 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuenov,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(added_time) = 12 AND DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) tuedic
    FROM shipping_details
    WHERE DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday'
```

It returns this json:

```
[{"DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday'":"1","mongen":"0","monfeb":"5","monmar":"0","monapr":"2","monmag":"40","mongiu":"63","monlug":"96","monago":"10","monset":"0","monott":"0","monnov":"0","mondic":"0"},{"DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday'":"1","mongen":"0","monfeb":"10","monmar":"3","monapr":"2","monmag":"38","mongiu":"59","monlug":"106","monago":"18","monset":"0","monott":"0","monnov":"0","mondic":"0"}]
```

How to modify query so it will return a json like this?

```
[{"added_time = 'Monday'","mongen":"0","monfeb":"5","monmar":"0","monapr":"2","monmag":"40","mongiu":"63","monlug":"96","monago":"10","monset":"0","monott":"0","monnov":"0","mondic":"0"},{"added_time = 'Tuesday'","tuegen":"0","tuefeb":"10","tuemar":"3","tueapr":"2","tuemag":"38","tuegiu":"59","tuelug":"106","tueago":"18","tueset":"0","tueott":"0","tuenov":"0","tuedic":"0"}]
```

Thanks in advance,

Nico

---

Ok after rethinking the query I need this json:

```
[{"added_time":"Monday","gen":"0","feb":"5","mar":"0","apr":"2","mag":"40","giu":"63","lug":"96","ago":"10","aet":"0","ott":"0","nov":"0","dic":"0"},{"added_time":"Tuesday","gen":"0","feb":"10","mar":"3","apr":"2","mag":"38","giu":"59","lug":"106","ago":"18","aet":"0","ott":"0","nov":"0","dic":"0"}]
```

The wrong query I have right now is this:

```
SELECT added_time, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) gen,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) feb,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mar,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) apr,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mag,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) giu,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) lug,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ago,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) aet,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ott,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) nov,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) dic
FROM shipping_details 
WHERE DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday'
UNION
SELECT added_time, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) gen,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) feb,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mar,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) apr,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) mag,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) giu,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) lug,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ago,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) aet,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ott,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) nov,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday' AND MONTH(added_time) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) dic
FROM shipping_details 
WHERE DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Tuesday'
```

It returns this wrong json:

```
[{"added_time":"2018-02-12 09:23:29","gen":"0","feb":"5","mar":"0","apr":"2","mag":"40","giu":"63","lug":"96","ago":"10","aet":"0","ott":"0","nov":"0","dic":"0"},{"added_time":"2018-02-13 09:32:07","gen":"0","feb":"10","mar":"3","apr":"2","mag":"38","giu":"59","lug":"106","ago":"18","aet":"0","ott":"0","nov":"0","dic":"0"}]
```

How to modify the query so it will be `added_time":"Monday"` and not `added_time":"2018-02-12 09:23:29`?

Thanks for your help,

Nico

Comment: That's not valid JSON, the first entry (`"added_time = 'Monday'"`) has no value associated with it.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected sql output of the query

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(added_time) = 'Monday',
```

to:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(added_time) as added_time,
```

Your version is added a boolean variable with no name -- hence the name is defaulted to the expression and the value is 0/1.  You want to name the column, so use `as`.  I would call it something like `day_of_week`, but you seem to prefer `added_time`.

I would suggest that you change the entire query to:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(added_time) as added_time,
       SUM(MONTH(added_time) = 1) as mongen,
       SUM(MONTH(added_time) = 2) as monfeb,
       . . .
FROM shipping_details
GROUP BY DAYNAME(added_time)
```

A single `GROUP BY` seems much simpler than a `UNION ALL`.  The use of `SUM()` with a boolean expression is a MySQL extension that is quite convenient (and makes sense in the context of other programming languages).